# islogical(img) returns false on inverted binary image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I wrote my own intensity transformation function to find the inverse of an image:

```
function EnhancedImage = transform(image,transformation)
if transformation == "inverse"
    if islogical(image)
        EnhancedImage = 1 - image;
        disp("Binary");
    elseif size(image,3) == 1
        EnhancedImage = 255 - image;
        disp("GreyScale");
    end
end
end
```

The function works fine if I send it a binary image like this:

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
img = transform(im2bw(im),'inverse');
```

However, when I again invert the resultant image `transform(img,'inverse')`it does not work due to the islogical(image) returning false (I checked). It returns true when I check it with the builtin imcomplement function. I fixed the problem by using `if all(image(:) == 0 |image(:) == 1)` in place of the islogical condition and it seems to work just fine but I can't figure out why the islogical one won't work and why it keeps returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To invert a logical image, use the Boolean negation operator:

```
EnhancedImage = ~image;
```

When using arithmetic (`1 - image`), the output is numeric, not logical. Logical matrices are a separate class, not considered numeric, but they automatically turn into numeric matrices to apply arithmetic operations.

Comment: Aren't all binary images logical images? If an image contains only 0 and 1 values, does matlab not infer it to be a binary image?

Comment: @MarijKhan: no, a `logical` matrix is different from a numeric matrix. Play around with `islogical`, `isnumeric`, and `class`. See also [this documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/fundamental-matlab-classes.html).